# Issue with JWTGuard and Laravel Sanctum for Authentication on cPanel Deployment

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-sanctum

I'm encountering a problem with my Laravel project related to authentication. Locally, I've implemented JWTGuard and i have tried Laravel Sanctum for user authentication, and it works perfectly. However, when I deploy the project to cPanel, the login process is successful, but I'm unable to use the generated token for other routes. I'm seeking help to understand and resolve this issue.

Here are the specifics of my setup and what I've tried so far:

Locally, I've successfully configured JWTGuard and Laravel Sanctum for authentication.

Upon deployment to cPanel, the login process works but the generated token doesn't work for other routes. The exact reason for this is unclear to me.

I've addressed CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) locally, and it's functioning correctly.

Here are the approaches I've tried to resolve the issue:

Adding headers in the beginning of the api.php file to handle CORS.

Implementing simple middleware to handle CORS.

I'm looking for suggestions, tips, or insights on what might be causing this problem specifically when deploying to cPanel. Any guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
   
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    }
}
```

at my api.php  file

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE", 
   "OPTIONS"');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin", "Content-Type", "X-Auth-Token", 
   "Authorization", "Accept", "charset", "boundary", "Content-Length"');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"');
```

this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydomain.net/$1 [R,L]

 </IfModule>

<FilesMatch .*\.ph.*$>
  Order Allow,Deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


<FilesMatch "index.php$">
 Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```